# Mocking Grails SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper Integration Testing

Tags: grails, groovy

I am trying to test an application that uses Backbone and sends a JSON object back to the server.

In the actual controller I can just do `request.JSON.update` to access the JSON value.

Now I usually set my params in teh test by creating a controller and then
just calling `controller.params.name = "foo"` etc etc.

Now this object is a `SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper` and I dont know how to mock one or create one. Here is some of my code:

```
  void testProcessBatch(){

    /* Set up the request here before calling the closure 'processBatch' 
    *  MockHttpServletRequest request = new MockHttpServletRequest();
    */ RequestContextHolder.setRequestAttributes(new ServletRequestAttributes(request));

    controller.processBatch.call()

    def result = controller.response.content
    def jsonResult = JSON.parse(controller.response.contentAsString)

    assertNotNull jsonResult.data
    assertNotNull controller.response.content
    assertEquals controller.response.status, 200 

  }
```

Comment: What object is a `SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper` and what part of this test isn't working for you?

Comment: I do not know how to even start and mock an object like that.